# Поиск минимальных значений и внесение их в список

Tags: python, функции, pandas

1. Поиск минимального значения в столбце "2" и запись индекса в res. "2" ==> "4"
2. Поиск минимального значения в столбце, который был найден в предыдущем пункте и запись индекса в res, исключая результаты, имеющиеся в res. "4" ==> "1".
3. Поиск минимального значения в столбце, который был найден в предыдущем пункте и запись индекса в res, исключая результаты, имеющиеся в res. "1" ==> "3".
4. Поиск минимального значения в столбце, который был найден в предыдущем пункте и запись индекса в res, исключая результаты, имеющиеся в res. "3" ==> "5".

   ```
         1             2          3          4          5
   1        inf   5.909091   8.636364   7.272727   4.454545
   2   7.222222        inf   8.666667   7.666667   1.777778
   3  15.833333  13.000000        inf   9.166667  14.666667
   4   4.444444   3.833333   3.055556        inf   4.833333
   5  24.500000   8.000000  44.000000  43.500000        inf
   ```

   Пример ниже. Но функцию не cмог применить

   ```
   res = ['2']
   def f():
       i = 0
       ret = d[res[i]].idxmin()
       i += 1       
   if ret not in res:
       res.append(ret)
   print(res)
   x = d.apply(f)
   ```

На выходе должно получится: `[2, 4, 1, 3, 5]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def f(col):
    ret = col.loc[~col.index.isin(res)].idxmin()
    if ret not in res:
        res.append(ret)

res = [2]
_ = df.iloc[:, 1:].apply(f)

print(res)
```

Результат:

```
[2, 4, 1, 3, 5]
```